# Remote Nodes is not detecting in cluster validate configuration in sql server 2019

Tags: sql-server, clustering, aws

I am not a professional DBA. In my organization, we are trying to implement active active node always on clustering. We have 2 nodes, primary and secondary. After installing WSFC, and during validation of clustering the remote node is not coming. Although We created a service account with the same and credentials on both servers but still remote node is not detected in each server. Please guide.

[image]

Comment: What do you mean that the "remote node is not detected"? The Windows cluster is not detecting both servers as up/online? What is it network like between the two servers? What have you done to validate network communication between the two servers?

Comment: I have launched 2 EC2 instances with SQL server standard 2019 installed and now configuring WSFC. So I enable failover then during failover validation. one server is not detecting second node. Although It can detect itself.

Comment: are you following those steps : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/create_cluster.html

Comment: That you are doing this in AWS is a very important detail! I'd suggest editing your question to add that detail. There are some specific instructions for creating an AG using EC2, especially around networking. If you haven't followed [these instructions](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ec2-windows-sql-server-always-on-cluster/), you can start there.

Comment: We have both nodes in different subnets. We are not able to validate the configuration. We have launched EC2 instances with SQL server Standard AMI.